# Simple interpolation in Matlab

Tags: matlab, interpolation

I want a simple interpolate. I see in many Matlab examples with **interp1** but... it is always with data points! It is not 1 dimensional data!

I want this function:

```
my_vector = interpolate(init, end, steps);
```

For example:

```
[1 10] % Interpolate in 7 steps --> [1 2.5 4 5.5 7 8.5 10]
[5 -5] % Interpolate in 3 steps --> [5 0 -5]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`linspace()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/linspace.html):

```
>> linspace(1, 10, 7)

ans =

    1.0000    2.5000    4.0000    5.5000    7.0000    8.5000   10.0000

>> linspace(5, -5, 3)

ans =

     5     0    -5
```

(I assume there's a mistake in your first example.)

Comment: Answered accepted! But one question: why this operation is not named interpolate?

Comment: I edited my first example because there is a mistake. Thanks NPE!